# Struct layout in apcs-gnu ABI

Tags: c, gcc, struct, arm, elf

For [this code](https://godbolt.org/g/huVqrd):

```
struct S {     unsigned char ch[2]; };

int main(void)
{
    _Static_assert( sizeof(struct S) == 2, "size was not 2");
}
```

using GCC (various versions) for ARM with the ABI `apcs-gnu` (aka. OABI, or EABI version 0), I get the assertion fails. It turns out the size of the struct is `4`.

I can work around this by using `__attribute__((packed))`;  but my questions are:

- What is the rationale for making this struct size `4`?
- Is there any documentation specifying the layout of structs in this ABI?

On the ARM website I found documentation for `aapcs` (EABI version 5) which does specify this struct as having a size of 2; but I could not find anything about `apcs-gnu`.

Comment: Padding is not a part of ABI. It might make a very good sense to have every piece of data to be aligned to 4-byte addresses due to the modern bus architectures.

Comment: Not sure about your specific platform but usually accessing memory as 4 bytes generates a faster code so maybe that's the rationale.

Comment: Why does your code require this struct to be 2 bytes in size?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Structure alignment rules are always defined in ABIs, otherwise one wouldn't be able to develop compliant programs in asm.

Comment: @BrianSidebotham That's structure size according to [APCS ABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a GCC-specific decision to trade-off size for performance. It can be overridden with `-mstructure-size-boundary=8`.

An excerpt from [source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/a568a3f7e458c8bcbc9e5bbdc3c67731b404a5c5/gcc/config/arm/arm.h#L621):

```
/* Setting STRUCTURE_SIZE_BOUNDARY to 32 produces more efficient code, but the
value set in previous versions of this toolchain was 8, which produces more
compact structures.  The command line option -mstructure_size_boundary=<n>
can be used to change this value.  For compatibility with the ARM SDK
however the value should be left at 32.  ARM SDT Reference Manual (ARM DUI
0020D) page 2-20 says "Structures are aligned on word boundaries".
The AAPCS specifies a value of 8.  */
#define STRUCTURE_SIZE_BOUNDARY arm_structure_size_boundary
```